# Rails route sometime got an error not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My Rails route sometimes get a not found error and resolves itself after a few seconds.

```
undefined local variable or method owner_root_path' for #<Owner::SessionsController:0x00007f30408d46f0>
/myapp/app/controllers/owner/sessions_controller.rb:30:increate’
/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in send_action'
/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:inprocess_action’
```

My routes config

```
# routes/owner.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: /^owner/ do
    root to: "owner/top_pages#show", as: :owner_root
    ...
  end
end

# application.rb

config.paths["config/routes.rb"] = %w(
  config/routes/owner.rb
  config/routes.rb
).map {|relative_path| Rails.root.join(relative_path)}
```

Does anyone know why it happened?

Comment: How often does this happen?

Comment: it doesn't happen often or periodically, about 1-2 months it happens again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. Because I've reload routes command on my application when I added a valid dynamic routes so sometime when app reload routes it will get the errors. Thank you for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1 guides introduced the `draw` macro which can be used to split a large route file into smaller files. You can read about it here: [Breaking up very large route file into multiple small ones](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#breaking-up-very-large-route-file-into-multiple-small-ones)

I don't know whether your version of Rails supports this macro. If it doesn't, then you can easily define a `draw` method yourself, using [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1611). It will be something like this:

```rb
  def draw(routes_name)
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/routes/#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
```

---

P.S: You should definitely check out [the commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/33bf253282496072aa130de4cb49d0031cb3a37c) that introduced this method/macro.